# My EC2 instance receives traffic for unrelated hostnames. How does this happen?

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a couple EC2 instances behind an Elastic Load Balancer.  These instances serve HTTP requests for a single web site.  I recently started looking at the HOST header of the traffic, because I am planning to split my app into virtual hosts.

With some regularity (dozens of times a day), I log a request for a host name that is totally unrelated to my servers.  As a couple examples, today I saw requests with the host names `ad.adserverplus.com` and `r1---sn-upfn-hp5e.c.youtube.com`.  I looked these up and the IP addresses are not the same as any of my servers, nor of the ELB, so I am trying to develop a theory as to how this happens.

I realize that someone could be spoofing the host header, but it happens often enough that I am pretty sure this is not what is going on.  My other idea is that somehow there is stale DNS data that just happens to resolve one of those hosts to my IP address, but again this seems like it could happen once in a great while but not regularly.  What are some other possibilities, and how might I verify / discredit them?

EDIT
I looked at some of the unexpected host names today, and it seems that they actually *do* resolve to an IP that is one of the possible IPs that my domain apex resolves to.  I use Route 53 for DNS, and I have the zone apex pointed to the ELB, so when I query the IP address for my domain, I get different answers depending on when I ask.  So this makes me very curious, how do these IP addresses get assigned to me and how does EC2 make sure they are not co-opting an IP address that someone else is already using.

Comment: As a guy who runs a small web host (outside of AWS), all I can say is that it is amazing how many requests I've gotten for ebay.com or yahoo.com over the years.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of reasons for this.  First you should understand that the public host name for your EC2 instances and load balancers have likely been used before.  If you have an elastic IP associated with your load balancer, it has also probably been used before.

As such you can get traffic to your servers that is intended for a previous tenant of that hostname of IP address that you are currently using.

One thing you can do is to configure your web servers to reject traffic (respond with 403) to traffic that is not arriving with the proper hostname specified or that comes from a specific external host.

Comment: I get that within EC2 the IP addresses get recycled, and that some mis-routed requests can result if someone's DNS cache is old.  But I thought this would only apply within EC2 -- I can't imagine a youtube.com machine ever having had an EC2 address.  Am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: @jfrank Sorry I guess I misread your question. I thought you were getting requests from those hosts (and you didn't know why), not that you were getting requests AS those hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP or your ELBs IP may have at one point in time been an open proxy. meaning that someone is hoping that you would forward the requests on to their intended destination.

but in general open port 80  to the internet and all kinds of bots and zombies will visit you with a pretty constant flow of dodgy requests. I would imagine though that the  \ec2 IP ranges would be a particularly juicy range to search for poorly patched websites to exploit.